# Can an Android widget toast be a voice?

Tags: android, toast

Is it possible that a Toast can be converted into voice? For example

`Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter origin address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

instead of showing the text "Please enter origin address" it will say this line.

Comment: have you tried TTS : take a look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Comment: A toast is text, its a little widget at the bottom.  But as zerocool said, you can use TTS to get the effect you want.